# Tor Browser Doesn't Play Videos From SkillShare.com On VPS

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, error, vps

I have another copy of Tor browser on my PC and it plays SkillShare videos just fine.

But the one on VPS can't play giving an error:

"The video is bad or in a format that can't be played in your browser"
media_err_decode

What can be causing the issue?

Everyone's help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: It probably doesn't have the correct video codecs (codices?) available to decode it. You might need to install gstreamer plugins or whatever the system happens to use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I have installed Gstreamer, VLC and K-Lite Code Pack on the VPS machine but the videos on SkillShare still don't play. I'm getting the same error code and after I click the OK button the loading wheel just keeps on spinning. What can be different between Tor browser installed on my home PC and Tor installed on VPS? I have checked and the settings are the same. Both are the fresh installations. Thanks.

Comment: It could be that it's a non-free encoding method that can't be redistributed without a license. .e.g [H.264](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Licensing)

Answer (score 1):

OK solved the problem after a thorough research.
This update was required:

Update for Desktop Experience Decoder for Windows Server 2008 R2 (KB2483177)

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13283

Thanks